# User cannot access crontab

Tags: cron

Oracle Linux 5.10

Root user can access crontrab, but not any other user.
There is no `/etc/cron.allow` and the `/etc/cron.deny` is an empty file.

Using Oracle user account:

```
[oracle@dub-ImrORA2 ~]$ crontab -e

Authentication failure
You (oracle) are not allowed to access to (crontab) because of pam configuration.

/etc/pam.d/crond listing:

auth       sufficient pam_env.so
auth       required   pam_rootok.so
auth       include    system-auth
account    required   pam_access.so
account    include    system-auth
session    required   pam_loginuid.so
session    include    system-auth
```

`crond` is running

```
[root@dub-ImrORA2 pam.d]# ps -aef | grep cron
root      3559     1  0 Jan29 ?        00:00:05 crond
root     25518 25279  0 13:19 pts/2    00:00:00 grep cron
```

Permissions on `crontab`

```
[root@dub-ImrORA2 ]# ls -al /usr/bin/crontab
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 315640 Dec 20  2011 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Permission on `/var/spool/cron/oracle`

```
[root@dub-ImrORA2 ]# ls -al /var/spool/cron/oracle
-rw------- 1 root root 125 Feb 24 11:43 /var/spool/cron/oracle
```

Comment: What do the logs say? `/var/log/cron` and `/var/log/secure`?

Comment: There are no entries for Oracle in var/log/cron and I don't see anything in var/log/secure that would indicate a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Problem resolved:

Change permissions on /usr/bin/crontab

```
[root@dub-ImrORA2 log]# ls -al /usr/bin/crontab
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 315640 Dec 20  2011 /usr/bin/crontab

[root@dub-ImrORA2 log]# chmod 4775 /usr/bin/crontab
[root@dub-ImrORA2 log]# ls -al /usr/bin/crontab
-rwsrwxr-x 1 root root 315640 Dec 20  2011 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Change owner on /var/spool/cron/oracle

```
[root@dub-ImrORA2 spool]# cd /var/spool/cron
[root@dub-ImrORA2 cron]# ls -al
total 24
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Feb 24 11:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Feb 13  2014 ..
-rw-------  1 root root  125 Feb 24 11:43 oracle

[root@dub-ImrORA2 cron]# chown oracle:root oracle
[root@dub-ImrORA2 cron]# ls -al
total 24
drwx------  2 root   root 4096 Feb 24 11:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root   root 4096 Feb 13  2014 ..
-rw-------  1 oracle root  125 Feb 24 11:43 oracle
```

Proof

```
[root@dub-ImrORA2 cron]# su - oracle
[oracle@dub-ImrORA2 ~]$ crontab -l
55 23 * * 0-4 /home/oracle/scripts/tblspc_usage_rpt.sh >> /home/oracle/scripts/tblspc_usage.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just comment `pam_access.so` in the `/etc/pam.d/cron`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it turns out that it was because my sssd daemon was disabled.  Starting (and enabling) sssd was the fix.